# permissions for enabling FTP upload and automatic plugin install in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I have a wordpress install and I want to be able to do the following two things:

1. automatically install plugins via the backend without providing an FTP/SSH user
2. upload files via FTP

To achieve point 1. I have read that I have to execute the following command: `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`. That means that the user/group `www-data` becomes owner of all files and folders in `/var/www`. After executing this command, the automatic installation of plugins works like a charm.

However, I now am not able to edit/upload files via FTP anymore. For FTP I use a different user named `ftpuser`. The following error is shown in my FTP client when I try to upload a new file: `[Filename] open for write: permission denied`

I put the `ftpuser` in the group `www-data`, hence I think that `ftpuser` should be able to write:

> root@xyz:~# grep 'www-data' /etc/group
>
> www-data:x:33:ftpuser

The file permissions on the folder `/var/www` are 755.

What is my issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try by using the below code in wp-config.php :

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Hope that will work.